# Passing data via URL with a post request in Slim

Tags: php, rest, spring-boot, api, slim

I’m creating an API and I’m wondering if there is any way to pass data via an URL with a post method for example

```
add?name={name}&age={age}…
```

I don’t have much experience with API development, but I remember this URL thingy worked in Spring Boot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create a route that handles POST HTTP requests without any query parameter.

```
$app->post('/add', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // get query parameters as an associative array
    $params = $request->getQueryParams();

    // return $params as a JSON data
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($params));
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

Then, make a POST HTTP request to that route with your query parameters: `/add?name=Foo&age=27`.

Output:

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "age": "27"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in URL like that in any type of HTTP Request.
That said when using POST / PUT / PATCH I would recommend using JSON payload sent as Request Body.

If you want to read an argument in Slim

```
<?php
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

    $name = $args['name'];

    // or
    $name = $request->getArgument('name');

    // When Request URL is
    // /hello/world?age=24
    // you can read the age argument as
    $name = $request->getArgument('age');

    // This behaviour is defined in PSR-7 and available across PHP frameworks

    return $response;
});
```

In plain PHP you can read an argument using superglobal $_GET or $_POST

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['age'];
```